# How do you delete temporary graph files using Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, python-toolbox, error-000725

I'm using the `arcpy.MakeGraph_management` and `arcpy.SaveGraph_management`  functions to create & save graphs in a Python Toolbox. The code works initially; however, subsequent use of the tool results in an error saying that the output from `arcpy.MakeGraph_management` (i.e., "temp_graph") already exists. If I close ArcMap and reopen it, I can again use this code fine, suggesting that the output from `arcpy.MakeGraph_management` is temporary; however I can't figure out how to delete this temporary graph in order to run the tool in succession or create multiple graphs in the same script.

```
# User provided input
folder = parameters[0].valueAsText
name = parameters[1].value
arcpy.env.workspace = folder

# Reference files
referenceFiles = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Reference Files")
graph_template = os.path.join(referenceFiles, "template_graph.grf")

# Create graph
arcpy.MakeGraph_management(graph_template, [...], "temp_graph")
arcpy.SaveGraph_management("temp_graph", "{0}/{1}_graph.pdf".format(folder, name))
```

Attempts at solution so far:

1)

```
arcpy.MakeGraph_management(graph_template, [...], "temp_graph")
arcpy.SaveGraph_management("temp_graph", "{0}/{1}_graph.pdf".format(folder, name))  
arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")
```

2)

```
if arcpy.Exists("temp_graph"):
    arcpy.Delete_management("temp_graph")
    arcpy.MakeGraph_management(graph_template, [...], "temp_graph")
    arcpy.SaveGraph_management("temp_graph", "{0}/{1}_graph.pdf".format(folder, name)) 
else:
    arcpy.MakeGraph_management(graph_template, [...], "temp_graph")
    arcpy.SaveGraph_management("temp_graph", "{0}/{1}_graph.pdf".format(folder, name))
```

Yet these tries still get me the same error:
 [image: Yet these tries still get me the same error]

I found someone with the same issue posted years ago: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/55685

I posted a response there in addition to posting it to Stack Exchange.

**Edit (5/11/17):**
I've discovered that the tool will run successfully if I set `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`, although I'd prefer an actual solution with deleting "temp_graph". I had tried @Midavalo's suggestion to use `arcpy.CreateUniqueName`, which was unsuccessful, but forgot to include it in the original post.

I've noticed that despite my attempt to setup a Current Worskpace, it's not working.:
[image]

This is so despite the code where I attempt to set my current workspace and also try using `arcpy.Describe()` to print the path of where "temp_graph" is located.

```
param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Output Folder",
    name="in_workspace",
    datatype="DEWorkspace",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input")
...
folder = parameters[0].valueAsText
arcpy.env.workspace = folder
arcpy.AddMessage("current workspace is {0}".format(arcpy.env.workspace))
desc = arcpy.Describe("temp_graph") OR desc = arcpy.Describe("{0}/temp_graph".format(folder))
print(desc.dataElement.catalogPath)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [CreateUniqueName](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/createuniquename.htm).  This tool appends incrementing numbers to the end of an input name until it finds one that is unique, e.g. `temp_graph_3`

```
uniquename = arcpy.CreateUniqueName("temp_graph")
arcpy.MakeGraph_management(graph_template, [...], uniquename)
arcpy.SaveGraph_management(uniquename, "{0}/{1}_graph.pdf".format(folder, name))
```

Comment: `arcpyCreateUniqueName()` isn't working in this context, not sure why...